# How to generate opencv-247.jar in Linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, opencv

I have tried to do in this way.But it did not create opencv-247.jarfile in opencv-2      opencv-2.4.8/build/bin directory.please any suggestion.

```
$ cd opencv-2.4.7

$ mkdir build

$ cd build/

$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr    
 /bin/gcc -D WITH_CUDA=ON .. 

$make -j4 

$ make install
```

Comment: It wont create it in opencv-2.4.8/... because you have cd to opencv-2.4.7

Comment: sorry it should be cd opencv-2.4.8

Answer (score 2):

You trying to make opencv 2.4.7:

```
$ cd opencv-2.4.7
```

Another suggestion:

Your procedure differ from suggested procedure on github.

I think that you can accomplish your task with this example:

```
cd ~/dev
git clone git://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
make -j8
```

For complete info follow this [link](https://github.com/magomimmo/opencv-start).

Answer (score 2):

Download and unzip OpenCV for Linux, then `cd` into the extracted folder.

Then:

```
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
make -j8
```

Now find inside of **release/lib** and **release/bin** the respective files -> `libopencv_javaXYZ.so` AND `opencv-XYZ.jar` and copy them into your project.

Note: ensure you have installed *cmake* and *build-essential* -- or expect interruptions.